# How to get tax settings and rates from recurly payment method

Tags: php, magento, recurly

I have setup tax for **US** and **New Zealand** in [Recurly](http://recurly.com) app. I'm using PHP **one-time transaction** in my magento platform. I have not setup tax in magento since i have setup in Recurly itself(If i setup in magento, tax is calculated in Magento as well as Recurly).

My problem is, if I place an order with *$300* from Magento, tax will be calculated in Recurly itself ex:*$300+$30*(tax) and order will be completed with $330 and display $300 in magento(Since Magento passed $300 only) in order total.

My question is, **whether they provide any api to pull Tax setting?** So that i can display that to customers and they can be aware of how much they are going to pay.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you trying to estimate tax values before sending the request to Recurly?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Recurly doesn't support pulling tax calculation data (i.e. tax rates) through the API yet. I would recommend to use a 3rd party to calculate your tax rates for now.

Comment: I can use it but my client already made setup for tax in Recurly admin, so the don't prefer to setup again in store. We are planning to remove tax setting from recurly and add it in Magneto store itself. So that we can avoid 2 times tax calculation :) Thanks for your time!